# Have trouble with monit (monit dead but subsys locked)

Tags: monitoring, service, monit

I installed monit on my centos 6/64bit and somethings wrong. Look at the shell :

```
[root@ND-1003 monit.d]# service monit start
Starting monit: monit: generated unique Monit id f8f62f27db2323649f105342f2fbf04d and stored to '/var/monit/id'
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@ND-1003 monit.d]# service monit status
monit dead but subsys locked
[root@ND-1003 monit.d]# service monit stop
Stopping monit:                                            [FAILED]
```

As you can see there is a message: **monit dead but subsys locked**

Anybody know how to correct this ?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the monit `statefile` variable in the configuration file. On the CentOS/RHEL RPMForge packaging of monit, the statefile defaults to `/var/monit/state`

The definition in the config file looks like:

`set statefile /var/monit/state`

Find the file, remove it, then restart the monit service.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the startup script, is there a lockfile or socket file that is searched for in a tmp directory of some kind? Rename that and see if it'll start.

Might be in something like /var/lock/subsys or /var/run.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little hackish, but it worked for me.

1. stop monit (`/etc/init.d/monit stop`)
2. start monit using this command (`/usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit.conf -l /var/log/monit.log -vv`)
3. test status (`/etc/init.d/monit status`)
   No subsys locked error is reported.

use `/usr/bin/monit -h` for more monit options.